# QSqlQuery::exec: database not open when I try to create a table in a new database

Tags: python, database, pyqt5, qsqlquery

I am creating a database GUI in PyQt5 and I am getting this `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open` I have looked at answers to similar questions but non was helpful.

```
self.db.setDatabaseName('demodatabase.db')
    
self.query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.db)
self.query.exec_("CREATE TABLE new1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100))")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very informative: You have to open the connection:

```py
self.db.setDatabaseName('demodatabase.db')
if not self.db.open():
    print(self.db.lastError().text()) 
self.query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.db)
self.query.exec_("CREATE TABLE new1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100))")
```

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc

Comment: @jamesmorgan  If answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour